# TypeError when i creating a 2d Array with Python

Tags: python, list, typeerror, python-3.8

this is the fragment where i have the error.

```
from nuevalista import newlist    
class Grid():
    def __init__(self, rows, columns, fill_value=None):
        self.data = newlist(rows,fill_value)
        for row in range(rows):
            self.data[row] = newlist(columns, fill_value)
```

this is the error messagge:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "***********", line 26, in 
matrix = Grid(3, 4)
File "***********", line 7, in **init**
self.data[row] = newlist(columns, fill_value)
TypeError: 'newlist' object does not support item assignment

And this is the imported code

```
class newlist:
def __init__(self,capacity,fill_value = None):
    self.capacity = capacity
    self.items = list()
    for _ in range(capacity):
        self.items.append(fill_value)

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.items)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.items)

def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.items)

def __getitem__(self,index):
    return self.items[index] 

def __setitems__(self,index,new_item):
    self.items[index] = new_item
```

Comment: `__setitem__` instead of `__setitems__`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @MechanicPig!, i don't understand how an "s" change the code? you have an explanation?